# Is there a contracted/casual form of でないと？

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions, copula, formality

でないと as in the conditional phrase.

> 例：これをやれ。でないと殺す。

> 例えば、じゃないと？

Never heard of it though. If there is no such thing then is でないと even considered formal in the first place or just neutral if it doesn't have a casual/contracted form?

Comment: Hi, shoryuu!  I've noticed that you add tags like [tag:kanji] and [tag:kanji-choice] to almost every question even though you've never asked a question related to kanji.  Perhaps you might consider trying to find tags that fit your questions specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the (Kanto) colloquial form 「で**ねえ**と」, but other than that, I don't think we have what you are looking for.

「じゃないと」 is different since it is the contracted form of 「で**は**ないと」 and not of 「でないと」.

Comment: Thank you. What is the meaning of ではないと though? Can't find any resources on it's uses. If you didn't make this distinction I would have probably thought the word is the same as でないと？

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be しないと though because you used やる, a verb, in the previous sentence, so you need to follow up with another verb.

Comment: I think でないと often follows an imperative, actually.  Maybe you can think of it as an elliptical form of （そう）でないと, meaning something like 'or else'.